# How do I install Chromium and Skype?

Tags: 12.04, installation, skype, chromium

Having just switched to Ubuntu from Mint I tried to install the Chromium browser and Skype. They gave the following errors:

**Chromium**

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
chromium-browser : Depends: libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3) but it is not going 
to be installed
```

**Skype:**

As soon as I open it with software center it appears

```
Cannot install libasound2:i386
```

Any ideas on how to fix either of these?

Comment: Run: `sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d libasound2:i386` and then try installing them again.

Comment: didnt work got this error as soon as I ran that command:            E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Try logging out and logging back in. Run the command again.

Comment: 1: Please ask one question at a time. You've asked two. 2: Please incorporate any additional information by editing the question.

Comment: again no effect same error

Comment: Did you ever get Skype installed?

Answer (score 1):

Use apt get for chromium, and it will deal with the rest of the missing packages :

Press `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser` and press **enter**.

after that, apt-get will install chromium and all its dependencies...

For skype, most people dont know that its easily available from ubuntu software center. Open another terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) and type `sudo software-center`, to enter the Ubuntu software center as a poweruser (root).

[image: Running software center as root]

Then whilst in there, go to the `System` category of apps, on the left side of the software center interface. Inside, search for skype and it should appear, but without a skype icon though.
Open the app synopsis and tick whatever plugins it is linked to, apply changes and then install. :)

Comment: That's a perfect answer!